# Visual Studio Team Services Test Running

Tags: selenium, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Apologies if similar has been asked before, I couldn't seem to find anything, just link me in the right direction if so.

I'm brand new to test automation, I will be writing selenium tests against a third party website hosted on an internal network. Our source control is provided by Visual Studio Team Services, although it is possible I can install TFS on premise.

Eventually I need to schedule test runs, I believe all this can be done with team services, seen some demo's, all good.

I will be using a URL to access the system under test which is on our internal network, if team services tries to run a selenium test and connect to the URL it will fail I imagine as it's running from wherever Microsoft are holding the code and building.

I don't think there would be a chance that we would allow Team services any access to our internal network if that was even possible.

So the question is, what are my options? can the build be moved from VS Team Services onto a local machine to run the tests with the internal URL? Is this a good idea if it can? Am i relying too much on the internet for testing on our internal network and is this a risk?

I have spent a bit of time on "the google" but struggling to find a great deal of information, it's possible I am asking the wrong questions.

Any help is greatly appreciated, links to articles are fine, don't mind doing the leg work, just need some pointers.

Many thanks for your help, apologies if any of that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. [Install a VSTS Build agent on-premise and connect it to VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows). The agent connects to VSTS using an outbound connection and it will be able to execute Builds and Release pipelines and from there orchestrate the execution of tests. 
   You can either put this agent in a specific Agent Pool or Agent Queue, or you can [add a Capability to it](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/getting-started/configure-agents#select-the-agent-for-a-task-phase) (e.g. "onprem"). By setting the Build Definition to use the specified Pool/Queue the agent will be selected. Or by [adding the Demand "onprem"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/getting-started/configure-agents#select-the-agent-for-a-task-phase) to your Build Definition it will ensure that it always requires that capability of any agent.
2. Use TFS 2015u3 or TFS2017 with the same agent, but that would mean you loose all the goodness that VSTS has to bring with regards to licenses, "free upgrades" and all.

### With regards to security.

Adding a agent to your network that executes commands queued on a cloud service adds a risk. You can minimize that risk by configuring the build agent with a limited account, use Active Directory to limit the machines this user can run processes on/logon to and you can limit the access to this agent through permissions on the Queue and Pool as well. You can ensure that the users who have access to this pool and all your VSTS administrators have configured 2-factor-authentication on their AAD account and if needed add IP access control to these accounts as well. It's recommended that users that administer such agent pools/queues do not have alternate credentials configured and that the Personal Access Token used to register the agent is scoped to the permissions required to do just that.

With these extra measures in place you'll have a pretty secure setup. And it beats the hassle of having to install, backup, maintain a couple of TFS servers on-premise.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks for that, much appreciated.

Comment: Just trying to get my head around the concept, apologies for my lack of knowledge, so will the build agent, bring down a copy of the code from VSTS, build it, and then execute on the machine that is hosting the agent? Many thanks for your time. Richie

Comment: Yes. Or download the binaries from VSTS and execute the tests. if you're in release mode.

Comment: @Richard You can mark it as answer if it helps you to solve your issue.